# How to change the value of select2 selectbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

```
days_of_week = [{id: 0, text: "Monday"},
                {id: 1, text: "Tuesday"},
                {id: 2, text: "Wednesday"},
                {id: 3, text: "Thursday"},
                {id: 4, text: "Friday"},
                {id: 5, text: "Saturday"},
                {id: 6, text: "Sunday"}]


$("#test").select2({
        data: days_of_week
    })


$("#date").datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd"

        })


$("#date").datepicker().on("changeDate", function(event) {
        var selected_date = $("#date").val()
        var day_name = moment(selected_date, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("dddd")
        $("#test").val(day_name)

    })
```

so basically what im trying to do here is select a date from a `datepicker`
get the day name of that date using `moment` and change the value of the `$("#test").select2()` to the selected `day_name` but what ends up happening is the value of `$("#test").select2()` is changed but it's changed to empty.

like for example. I the default value for select2 was a `"Monday"` selecting a date the current value of select2 is now empty.

How do we change the value of select2 using jquery?

I've read the other older posts on here. but they don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example the `value` of your select2 selectbox is an ID (0-6). You are trying to set the value to the label of the selectbox. Also you need to manually trigger a "change" event on a select2 box using.... `.trigger("change");` as per [documentation](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic).

So you have to do something like this:

```
$("#date").datepicker().on("changeDate", function(event) {
    var selected_date = $("#date").val();
    //var day_name = moment(selected_date, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("dddd");
    var day_index = moment(selected_date, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("d"); //returns day of week 0-6
    $("#test").val(day_index).trigger("change");
})
```

PS: Your javascript is missing a whole bunch of semicolons

Comment: I know my js missing a lot of all the semi-colons. force of habit with python hahaha. so that's what the val was for. It makes sense now.